# Using Java's Robot to hold a key down

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

Currently i'm trying to have java hold down a key like follows:

```
Robot rob;

rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
Thread.sleep(3000);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

This should hold enter down for 3 seconds, causing the repeating effect after a second or so. In other words, if you were to manually hold the "r" key, it would first type r, and then after about a second it would go like rrrrrrrr. I want this effect from the robot. I also tried:

```
curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while(System.currentTimeMillis() - curTime < duration)
{
rob.keyPress(whatever);
}
rob.keyRelease(whatever);
```

This, however, is extremely sensitive and a duration of 1 second outputs... well, as many whatever's as your computer can in 1 second. Thousands of lines worth. This is not my intention. Any ideas? Thanks!

P.S. The reason I want this behavior is because im writing a little scripting language to automate games with. If I want to hold the up arrow key like a normal person, I think that I need the behavior i'm talking about.

Edit:

Since there seems to be some confusion, I appologize. Let me elaborate. In my first code peice, if I choose "r" to be the character, it will just print ONE r regardless of the duration. If you, on your keyboard, press "r" for 5 seconds, it will go -> r...rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr where ... means like a second of time. That is the behavior I want, but I wont get it. The second code is where I try to spam click "press", but this literally types "r" EVERY time it executes. So if I am in a timed loop for a duration, every time that loop iterates it will send the "r" button. That's not what I want. What I want, again , is the same result that would happen as if you pushed r down on your keyboard for 3 seconds. First its just one r, and then rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr. I'm not even sure what the release() method does... I figured if you left it on press without release, it would just SPAM the screen in a loop! Why wouldnt it, the key is PRESSED? This is what is confusing me. Apparently when a key is pressed it doesnt STAY pressed.

Comment: You don't tell us what or how your code is not working.

Comment: Can I just verify, is you current code producing repeated characters or not?  My tests don't

Comment: @MadProgrammer: you're right. The problem is that there is no `keyDown()` method for Robot. I suppose this can be done in a platform dependent way with JNI or JNA.

Comment: I assumed keyPress() was keyDown(), since there is a keyRelease(). Hmm

Comment: I would recommend using AutoHotKey instead. Is that an option?

Comment: AutoHotKey is a fine scripting language. I actually decided to make a less complex one on my own for some custom things. For instance, I made a cubic spline interpolation between source and destination, as well as a travel time for a mouse click. This will fool the client into thinking a user is actually moving the mouse in a natural way... you know, instead of either "teleporting" to the location or moving in a straight line (near impossible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can't get key repeats to occur when using `Robot` and `keyPress`.

In this case, you may need to produce a "psudo" "long" key press.

Basically, I tried something like this:

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.setAutoDelay(1);

int duration = 3000;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
}
```

Which, rapidly pressed and releases the key over a period of time...

And I used this to test it...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestRobot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestRobot();
    }

    public TestRobot() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ta = new JTextArea(20, 20);
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ta.requestFocusInWindow();
                    ta.append("Start\n");
                    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

                            Robot bot = new Robot();
                            bot.setAutoDelay(1);

                            int duration = 3000;
                            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                                bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                                bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
                            }
                            return null;

                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void done() {
                            ta.append("\nDone");
                        }
                    };
                    worker.execute();
                }
            });
            add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }
    }
}
```

**Updated**

With a little testing, I was able to get this to work...

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.setAutoDelay(50);

int duration = 3000;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
}
bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
```

Now, if you play around with the `autoDelay` property, you can adjust the time (in milliseconds) between each event, which may produce a more desirable effect...

Comment: Yes, you're updated solution seems to be similar to the other answer. That is, put delays in between each key press. So if the delay is 50ms, and the duration is 1000 ms, we will see 20 presses. It seems that there is no direct way to simulate a keyboard hold without actually creating "hacky" code to achieve the affect. For now it seems ill have to enter the game and play with implementations on the "hold key" script command, and see which one works the best. Thank you for your time and answer, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `for` loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    rob.keyPress(whatever);
```

Or, to emulate the hold down effect you want:

```
rob.keyPress(whatever);
Thread.sleep(500);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rob.keyPress(whatever);
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

If you want more "organic" behaviour, just randomize the number of iterations.

Comment: You're second code block seems to be exactly how it really works... That is, "r", then 1/2 second, then rrrrrr every 10 ms or so. I guess the question is how it happens from the keyboard. If im trying to hold "right arrow" in a game, and i hold it on the keyboard, I get a certain result. If I just spam keyPress in a while loop, will it be the same effect, or do I need little 10 ms buffers like you do? I guess ill have to experiment, but thank you for your answer

Comment: @user2045279 That is something you will have to test. I don't know how the application you're trying to control will process so many keyboard events coming in at once.

Comment: I tried 50 ms on the move. It looks exactly as if I were to press it on the keyboard. Thank you for your approach, it seems to work great with 50ms delays.