# How to keep key pressed for some time and then release in JAVA / Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, keypress

I am looking for code to keep key pressed for some time and then release. 
e.g Keep right arrow key pressed for 5 seconds and then release. (I do not want repetitive key press and key release for 5 seconds, so not using any looping)

Currently using below code, but this is not working:

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
```

Comment: What is your exact usecase which you are trying to automate? Are you seeing any error?

Comment: this may be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333187/using-javas-robot-to-hold-a-key-down

Comment: @DebanjanB - I am trying to automate video player where if we press right arrow key it forwards the video, but for that I need to keep arrow key pressed for at least 5 seconds.

Comment: @Murthi - Given solution repeating the steps, i.e press - release - press - release - press - release (till the loop ends). I am looking for --> Key Press - Hold for 'x' seconds - Release.